# Magento 2 : Need HH:MM:SS selector in custom module in UI without AM and PM

Tags: magento2, ui, ecommerce-tracking, timepicker

I have a requirement to show time picker to input hh:mm:ss for a user in a custom UI module in Magento 2 .
It needs to allow to enter  hours from 1 to 6, minutes from 0-59, same for seconds .. I don’t want to associate date with this !
Pls guide on how do I achieve this ! I tried using time picker but I am not able to remove AM and PM from it ..

Appreciate your help !

Comment: hello, please check it i will explain step by step

Comment: please check my answer let me know any issue.?

Answer (score 0):

hello dear I do to your requirements if you want to. so please check the below code. I think that is helpful for you.

please go to /var/www/html/project/app/code/Test/Uiform/view/adminhtml/ui_component/test_uiform_blog_form.xml

above code is my module-related file path. so you can go with your module path.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="general">
  <field name="time_field">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Time</item>
        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">time_field</item>
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Test_Uiform/js/form/element/time</item>
        <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm:ss</item>
        </item> 
    </item>
</argument>
 </field>
 </fieldset>
 </form>
```

add the above code to your.xml file.

now to create a new .js file check the below path.

/var/www/html/project/app/code/Test/Uiform/view/adminhtml/web/js/form/element/time.js

```
define([
'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/date'
 ], function(Date) {
'use strict';

return Date.extend({
    defaults: {
        options: {
            showsDate: false,
            showsTime: true,
            timeOnly: true,
            hourMin: 1,
            hourMax: 5
        },

        elementTmpl: 'ui/form/element/date'
    }
     });
});
```

After applying the below command. your project root directory.

```
sudo php bin/magento s:up && sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile && sudo php bin/magento s:static-content:de -f && sudo php bin/magento c:f && sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated
```

I will share my screenshot as per your requirement. if any issue then tell me.

I hope that is helpful for you. so please accept my answer and upvote me.
[image]